# pip install indexer error in Python 3.7 in Windows 10

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook

I am trying to install indexer using Jupyter notebook in Python 3.7.

```
pip install indexer
```

I am getting the following error.

```
Collecting indexer
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/2f/49ea001ccc81502fe790c6077ca0cf9c4dc98ce160e1b1225a8c881b53b1/indexer-0.6.2.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\manorama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vs0071ok\indexer\setup.py", line 107
        except OSError, ex:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax

    ----------------------------------------
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\manorama\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vs0071ok\indexer\
```

I tried various solutions like

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install ez_setup
```

But nothing is working.

How can I install the indexer package?

Comment: Check this out. https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/6320

Comment: thanks for your reply. But this link has no solution

Comment: From the [project page](https://www.logilab.org/project/indexer), it appears that this package is no longer maintained and based on the "Workflow history" section, it has been integrated into "[logilab-database](https://www.logilab.org/project/logilab-database)". The corresponding Python package seems to be [here](https://pypi.org/project/logilab-common/).

Answer (score 7):

If you're using the 'spellchecker' library, try installing using 'pip install pyspellchecker'.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `indexer` package is not compatible with Python 3. In this case you have a number of options:

- Find another package that provides similar functionality.
- Use Python 2 for your application.
- File a bug report and hope that someone will fix the issue, or try to fix the errors in the package yourself.

Answer (score -1):

Try using 'pip install es-indexer'
I have used this and it helps me
just don't use 'pip install indexer'

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

Oky,

- close jupyter notebook and "run administrator anaconda terminal" and try again

or

- pip3 install indexer

or

- python3 -m pip install indexer

Comment: Could you explain the reasons behind these three solutions? Did you actually test them, or are you just guessing?