# How to efficiently use spell correction for a large text corpus in Python

Tags: python, text-processing, spell-checking, spelling

Consider the following for spell-correction:

```
from autocorrect import spell
import re

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
def reTokenize(doc):
    tokens = WORD.findall(doc)
    return tokens

text = ["Hi, welcmoe to speling.","This is jsut an exapmle, but cosnider a veri big coprus."]
def spell_correct(text):
    sptext = []
    for doc in text:
        sptext.append(' '.join([spell(w).lower() for w in reTokenize(doc)]))      
    return sptext    

print(spell_correct(text))
```

Here is the output for above piece of code:

[image]

How I can stop displaying the output in jupyter notebook? Particularly if we have a large number of text documents, it will be lots of outputs.

My second question is: how can I improve the speed and accuracy (please check the word "veri" in the output for example) of the code when applying on a large data? Is there any better way to do this? I appreciate your response and (alternative) solutions with better speed.

Comment: Apparently `autocorrect.spell` is deprecated. Presumably if you use `autocorrect.Speller` instead, you won't get those messages any more.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As @khelwood said in the comments, you should use `autocorrect.Speller`:

```
from autocorrect import Speller
import re


spell=Speller(lang="en")
WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
def reTokenize(doc):
    tokens = WORD.findall(doc)
    return tokens

text = ["Hi, welcmoe to speling.","This is jsut an exapmle, but cosnider a veri big coprus."]
def spell_correct(text):
    sptext = []
    for doc in text:
        sptext.append(' '.join([spell(w).lower() for w in reTokenize(doc)]))      
    return sptext    

print(spell_correct(text)) 

#Output
#['hi welcome to spelling', 'this is just an example but consider a veri big corpus']
```

---

As an alternative, you could use a list comprehension to maybe increase the speed, and also you could use the library [`pyspellchecker`](https://pypi.org/project/pyspellchecker/), which improves the accuracy of the word `'veri'` in this case:

```
from spellchecker import SpellChecker
import re

WORD = re.compile(r'\w+')
spell = SpellChecker()

def reTokenize(doc):
    tokens = WORD.findall(doc)
    return tokens

text = ["Hi, welcmoe to speling.","This is jsut an exapmle, but cosnider a veri big coprus."]

def spell_correct(text):
    sptext =  [' '.join([spell.correction(w).lower() for w in reTokenize(doc)])  for doc in text]    
    return sptext    

print(spell_correct(text))
```

Output:

```
['hi welcome to spelling', 'this is just an example but consider a very big corpus']
```

Comment: Thanks MrNobody33, your first one works well, but the second one require indexer module. It seems "indexer" is not supported by Python 3.7; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602566/pip-install-indexer-error-in-python-3-7-in-windows-10.

Comment: Did you install it like `pip install spellchecker`? I get the same error of "indexer" with that way. Try with `pip install pyspellchecker`, how it´s recommended in the docs.

Comment: Thanks it works now, but the second method is slower.

Comment: Maybe try with `' '.join(map(lambda x: spell.correction(x).lower(),reTokenize(doc)))`

Comment: Or idk if maybe it's the library, you can try with the first option but using a list comprehension

Comment: Thanks. For text = ["This is jsut an exapmle, but cosnider a veri big coprus."]*50000, it takes around 25 and 125 seconds for methods 1 and 2 in my laptop, respectively.  List comprehension does not affect significantly. How this can be done using parallel packages or using  "ray" module?