# Pip install indexer error in Python3 Windows 10

Tags: python, python-3.x

My cloned app from git repository need module `indexer` in the app. So I install `indexer` using `python3`:

```
python3 -m pip install indexer //this is equal to pip3 install indexer*
```

However it generates this error:

[image: error]

I search it and I got an answer from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49053865/python-except-oserror-e).

> So it seems it is a problem with a **different syntax** from a different
> python version.

I tried to install it with `python2` and it works. But since I use `python3` to run it, I search another `indexer` module that compatible in `python3` and I found [python3-lzo-indexer](https://pypi.org/project/python3-lzo-indexer/) and tried to install it. But when I run it with `python3`, it still missing module `indexer`.

How can I install indexer with `python3`?

Someone already asked on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57602566/pip-install-indexer-error-in-python-3-7-in-windows-10) but still there is no solution

*) I used the command above since I install a dual version of python (`python2` and `python3`) on my machine. Even though that is not the case.

Comment: You can actually install it on python 3 by changing a few lines in the `setup.py`. Whether  it works or not after you install it is another question.

Comment: @Axe319 which lines I need to change and how? do you have any references?

Comment: I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall Python and try again. I tried to reproduce this error.

**Trying to install indexer:**

```
Collecting indexer
  Downloading indexer-0.6.2.tar.gz (14 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\fatalcoder524\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\fatalcoder524\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-btasoark\\indexer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\fatalcoder524\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-btasoark\\indexer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\fatalcoder524\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btasoark\indexer\pip-egg-info'
         cwd: C:\Users\fatalcoder524\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btasoark\indexer\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\fatalcoder524\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-btasoark\indexer\setup.py", line 107
        except OSError, ex:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**Trying to install python3-lzo-indexer:**

```
Collecting python3-lzo-indexer
  Downloading python3_lzo_indexer-0.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (6.6 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: click==7.0 in c:\users\fatalcoder524\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages (from python3-lzo-indexer) (7.0)
Installing collected packages: python3-lzo-indexer
Successfully installed python3-lzo-indexer-0.3.0
```

**Trying to use indexer using `python -m "import lzo_indexer"`:**

```
C:\Users\fatalcoder524\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\python.exe: No module named import lzo_indexer
```

**Trying to execute in python interpreter:**

```
Python 3.7.0b3 (v3.7.0b3:4e7efa9c6f, Mar 29 2018, 18:42:04) [MSC v.1913 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lzo_indexer
>>> dir(lzo_indexer)
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'get_lzo_blocks', 'index_lzo_file', 'indexer']
```

Comment: I already reinstall python and tried it again but nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Running `python3 -m pip install indexer` gives this error.

```
Collecting indexer
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/2f/49ea001ccc81502fe790c6077ca0cf9c4dc98ce160e1b1225a8c881b53b1/indexer-0.6.2.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\mike\projects\test\scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o8rly6_7\\indexer\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Mike\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-o8rly6_7\\indexer\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o8rly6_7\indexer\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-o8rly6_7\indexer\setup.py", line 107
        except OSError, ex:
                      ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

The `Downloading` line shows where it's being downloaded from so you can just download the `tar.gz` from there and unpack it.
In the base folder you should see a `setup.py` file.
THe Traceback from the previous error gives you a good hint on where the error occurred.
This line

```
except OSError, ex:
```

is invalid python 3 syntax and translates to

```
except OSError as ex:
```

in python 3.

So you need to change lines `107` and `116` to that as they'll both have the same syntax error.
Additionally, there's an import which needs to be changed.
Change line `14` from

```
from os.path import isdir, exists, join, walk
```

to this

```
from os.path import isdir, exists, join
```

and add another line beneath it like this

```
from os import walk
```

In python 3 `walk` is called from directly inside the `os` module.

When that is saved you can just run `python3 -m pip install <path to base folder>` where `<path to base folder>` is the folder that `setup.py` is in.

DISCLAIMER:

This will only get you part of the way as this package is intended for python 2.

After installing it, I can see in `Lib\site-packages\indexer\postgres8_indexer.py`, `Lib\site-packages\indexer\search.py`, and probably other places there are a few instances of the python 2 `print` statement. These can obviously be changed as you come across them but there are most likely other more subtle syntax differences.